# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getProjectId()'

Tags: java, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting error while implementing firebase push notifications in java backend server and trying to send push notification to device token.

The [DEFAULT] app is initialised successfully but when i try to send notification like this:

```
public void sendToToken() throws FirebaseMessagingException {
        
        String registrationToken = "1312313132";
        
        
        Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("score", "850")
                .putData("time", "2:45")
                .setToken(registrationToken)
                .build();

        String response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().send(message);
        
        System.out.println("Successfully sent message: " + response);
        
      }
```

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Stringcom.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.getProjectId()
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices

Answer (score 0):

It looks like have problem in your dependency setting.

I suggest check Gradle or Pom, and check your dependency setting.

If it is okay, Keep following down error messages, and find which library is missing.

It is too short error message to find solution correctly

Comment: i have installed the libs that were missing before but cannot find which lib is missing

Comment: I found similar problem on GitHub https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/4946

Comment: It seems specific SDK version issue